# How to sort tuples

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples

I wanna know how can I sort the countries alphabetically out of a tuples.

```
cities_countries=[('doha','qatar'),('ankara','turkey'),('rome','italy'),('brussels','belgium')]
```

the result should be:

```
belgium, brussels
italy, rome
qatar, doha
turkey,ankara
```

if possible can I use for loops

Comment: Do not vandalize your own question please.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line using built in sorted

```
cities_countries=[('doha','qatar'),('ankara','turkey'),('rome','italy'),('brussels','belgium')]

sorted(cities_countries, key=lambda x: x[1])
# [('brussels', 'belgium'),
# ('rome', 'italy'),
# ('doha', 'qatar'),
# ('ankara', 'turkey')]

# and to get it in the order you want
map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), sorted(cities_countries, key=lambda x: x[1]))

# [('belgium', 'brussels'),
# ('italy', 'rome'),
# ('qatar', 'doha'),
# ('turkey', 'ankara')]
```

Comment: can't I just do it in a simple way ? using a for loop ?

Comment: How could a `for` loop be more simple than a single function call?